# storage problem from internal storage to phone storage

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, insufficient-memory

In my mobile there are three types of storage- 1) internal storage 2) phone storage and 3) storage card. My internal storage is almost full and i am not able to do upgrade the apps or download new apps. I want to move few apps to other storage but not able to as it does not show the option to move to phone storage or sd card. Please help me as soon as possible.

Comment: What device and android version are you using? Which apps are you trying to move? Furthermore: Check the [`App2SD`](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) tag-wiki.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) is a good starting point for your issue. It gives you some background information, and has some first aid as well.

Comment: Try using link2sd app. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not rooted, you can merely do anything beside deleting personal data (e.g. pictures, movies) apps and cache of apps.
You can move pictures to the external sdcard with the internal file explorer.
First thing, delete the cache of your browser, e.g. Chrome, often this is big.